# Is there a way to merge two dataframes with slightly different string values in columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I am working on an R task, that includes working with 2 separate data frames. And I need to merge them by one column (with geographical names), in which values are sometimes a bit different like:

"A Coruna" and "Coruna, A", "Alicante/Alacant" and "Alicante", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife" and "4  Santa Cruz".

Pairs lake those should be taken as the same values when merging the data frames.
So the result of merging would be a data frame like:

```
province | males.2018 | males.2013 | area
```

Is there some way to do it, without using extra libraries?

Thank you

[image: First data frame]
[image: Second data frame]

Comment: why don't you try to add a column with the spanish zip code for each province and use it to merge. That way you will always have the guarantee that it is rightly done

Comment: Please never paste an image as an example data, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this without any external packages, perhaps using `agrep`?

The **fuzzyjoin** package was developed precisely for this situation. So why not take advantage of it. However, the values that you want to match on don't seem very similar, even though you said: "sometimes the values are a *bit different*". So the fuzzyjoin solution may not be able to help you here. You can see from the following:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- data.frame(province1=c("A Coruna", "Alicante/Alacant", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife"))
df2 <- data.frame(province1=c("Coruna, A", "Alicante", "4 Santa Cruz"))

data.frame(df1, df2)
               province1  province1.1
1               A Coruna    Coruna, A
2       Alicante/Alacant     Alicante
3 Santa Cruz de Tenerife 4 Santa Cruz
```

The following attempt to merge returns no matches:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "province1")
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Now try fuzzy matching. The default distance used for joining is 2.

```
stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "province1")
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: province1.x <chr>, province1.y <fct>
```

This returns no records. So try increasing the distance threshold. For this small example, the first record needs a `max.distance` of 5 to be deemed a match.

```
stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "province1", max_dist = 5)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  province1.x province1.y
  <chr>       <fct>      
1 A Coruna    Coruna, A
```

You have to increase the threshold further to get more matches. But doing this fails because "A Coruna" also matches "Alicante"!

```
stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "province1", max_dist = 7)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  province1.x province1.y
  <chr>       <fct>      
1 A Coruna    Coruna, A  
2 A Coruna    Alicante
```

Increasing the threshold to 8 gets "Alicante", but it is still matched with "A Coruna".

```
stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "province1", max_dist = 8, distance_col = "dis")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  province1.x      province1.y   dis
  <chr>            <fct>       <dbl>
1 A Coruna         Coruna, A       5
2 A Coruna         Alicante        7
3 Alicante/Alacant Alicante        8
```

So you can see, this isn't going to work for values that are not very similar. You may need to do some data cleaning prior to using this method. There are various methods in this function that you can try. Or use some iterative approach with increasing thresholds so that records that have already been matched are not matched again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way is to fix the Province names in both data frames: use the [ISO 3166-2:ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:ES) codes added in a new column instead. If you paste the data as the output of `dput` to the question, I can provide a code to do that.